# T-SQL, Remove space in string

Tags: t-sql, replace

I have two strings in SQL and the REPLACE function only works on one of them, why is that?

Example 1:

```
SELECT REPLACE('18 286.74', ' ', '')
```

Example 2:

```
SELECT REPLACE('z z', ' ', '')
```

Example 1's output is still "18 286.74" whereas Example 2's output is "zz". Why does SQL not react the same way to both strings?

UPDATE:

When running `select replace('123 123.12', ' ', '')` that works fine, still not with '18 286.74'.

Comment: This is also working on a colleague's pc and we running the queries against the same database server

Comment: This works in SQL Server 2008, as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Test it the following way.

```
select unicode(substring('18 286.74', 3, 1))
```

If the code returns 32 then it's a space, if not, it's a different Unicode character and your replace ' ' won't work.

Comment: You can always do REPLACE('18 286.74', CHAR(160), '') in the case of non-breaking spaces

Comment: @Jabezz This unicode test feature is really cool! Was really helpful in diagnosing my mystery character :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe cast is needed.

UPD: or not(on sql 2005 works fine too)

Comment: Casting a varchar to a varchar, I doubt it but I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is a space? i.e. the **same** whitespace character that you are passing as the second argument? The code you've posted works fine for me on SQL Server 2008.

Re working on your friends PC - perhaps the whitespace got normalized when you sent it to him?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using non-breakable space.

I could reproduce it by typing `ALT+0160` into the number in `SELECT REPLACE('18 286.74', ' ', '')`

Could you please issue this following:

```
SELECT CAST('18 286.74' AS BINARY), REPLACE('18 286.74', ' ', '')
```

by copying the `'18 286.74'` from `REPLACE` into `CAST`?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and found that it was a char(10) (line feed). when copied out of Managment Studio it became a char(32) but in the record it was a char(10) try

```
Select Replace(@string, char(13), '')
```