# REPLACE not working on sql table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I've tried select `REPLACE(' this is a user name', ' ', '')` and it gives me 'thisisausername' which is supposed to be.

My problem is, when I try to use `REPLACE` on selecting a table column, it doesn't work!

My query:

```
SELECT REPLACE(UserName, ' ', '') as UserName FROM MY_TABLE
```

it still gives me usernames with spaces! Am I doing something stupid?

Comment: What's the column data-type?

Comment: What database are you using? This works fine for me using MS SQL assuming username is a varchar(n).

Comment: Perhaps they are non-standard unicode whitespace or tabs, see what `unicode(substring(fld, X, 1))` returns where X is the position of a space

Comment: Are you sure it's a space in your username column, and not a tab character?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @haim770 the column data-type is NVARCHAR(100)

Comment: @jpw i'm on sql 2008 r2

Comment: @Shiva actually i'm not sure if it is a space or a tab char but i tried also this REPLACE(REPLACE(UserMain.UserName, ' ', ''), char(9), '') because i know that char(9) is a tab char if i'mright

Comment: What does the username string look like exactly? Can you give an example where it fails?

Comment: Your expression is correct. What database are u using

Comment: @jpw this is an example of where it fails ' n.miranda'

Comment: @EdwardManda i'm using SQL 2008 R2

Comment: @eytch that looks like a period not a space :P

Comment: @Kritner, it's a leading space

Comment: @Kritner yes there is a period but also there is a space before letter N

Comment: what is `unicode(left(field, 1))` for the ` n.miranda` value?

Comment: @eytch could you try an LTrim(UserName) and see if you still have the leading character?  Maybe it could be something that "looks" like a space.

Comment: @AlexK. it's 160 for unicode(left(field, 1))

Comment: @Kritner still the same

Comment: Thats NO-BREAK SPACE (U+00A0) so `replace(fld, char(160), '')` for that specific case. I would normalize everything to ' ' and check the input sanitization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321946/t-sql-remove-space-in-string), check the comment under the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1321992/1225845)

Comment: @AlexK. it worked! thankyou so much, you can post it as an answer so i can mark it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> @AlexK. it's `160` for `unicode(left(field, 1))`

160 is Unicode NO-BREAK SPACE so that's what you need to replace:

```
replace(UserName, char(160), '')
```

You could update everything replacing `char(160)` with a whitespace `' '` and then just use your original query in the future (perhaps also ensuring such values cannot be entered in the future)